# Cannot start the provider *file.Provider: field not found, node: entrypoint in Traefik configuration

Tags: traefik

I want to redirect the request to a non-dockerized webapp running in another host using traefik.

I am starting traefik with docker-compose with the following yml :

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.file=true"
      - "--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/rules.toml"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8050:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - "./rules.toml:/etc/traefik/rules.toml"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=false
```

And my rules.toml file is :

```
[entrypoints]
    [entrypoints.http]
     address = ":8080"

[providers]
[providers.file]
[http]
    [http.routers]
       [http.routers.auth-router]
          rule = "Path(`/auth`)"
          service = "auth"
          entrypoint=["http"]

    [http.services]
          [http.services.auth.loadbalancer]
            [[http.services.auth.loadbalancer.servers]]
              url = "http://myhost.com:8080/auth"
```

Whenever user opens http://localhost:8080/auth, traefik should redirect them to http://myhost.com:8080/auth, that is my requirement. but I'm getting the following error during traefik startup

```
Cannot start the provider *file.Provider: field not found, node: entrypoint"
```

How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error makes it seem like it's a file provider issue, but I think it's just a type on your part -- should be `entryPoints` (uppercase P) in your rules.toml file

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
     address = ":8080"

[providers]
[providers.file]
[http]
    [http.routers]
       [http.routers.auth-router]
          rule = "Path(`/auth`)"
          service = "auth"
          entryPoints = ["http"]

    [http.services]
          [http.services.auth.loadbalancer]
            [[http.services.auth.loadbalancer.servers]]
              url = "http://myhost.com:8080/auth"
```

Comment: Thanks @Glen Yu, I tried that. It did not work. I completely removed the entry point section from rules.toml, still I was getting the same error.

Comment: You have 3 places you need to make that edit.  In the first 2 lines + in your `http.routers`.  I edited my original response to add that in

Comment: Sorry for that, I changed the P but did not change the point to Points in sub elements. that was causing that issue. Do I need to add anything to make the redirection work. Currently, it is not redirecting the page to http://myhost.com:8080/auth, when I open http://localhost:8080